# OAuthSwift : error

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

I just downloaded the OAuthSwift Project and I would like to check the demo, but when I am compiling, I got a lot of errors,
Why ?

[image]

Comment: Because you've got a lot of syntax problems.  Take some time, go through them one at a time.  (And when I say that, I don't mean open 21 separate questions for your 21 different errors... I mean go fix as many of those as you can on your own before you return.  If you don't understand them, start with something simpler.)

Comment: I don't understand why, I just loaded the OAuthSwift project, I didn't changed anything

Comment: nhgrif, I am not that guy who post 10 topics for 10 problems, I try to check the problem by myself before, but as I am beginning when I am totally lost I open one topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code uses the "forced failable conversion operator" `as!`, 
which was introduced with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta).

The error messages indicate that you compile the project with an
earlier Xcode version, probably with Xcode 6.2 (Swift 1.1).

There are *a lot of incompatible changes* between Swift 1.1 and Swift 1.2,
these are documented in the "Xcode 6.3 beta Release Notes"
(available on https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).
The [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/) has also
some posts about Swift 1.2.

You can either download the current Xcode 6.3 beta, or try to get an earlier
release of the project which is Swift 1.1 compatible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, I spent hours to try understanding why it didn't work, stackoverflow was my last solution... I am downloading it